# Error when using simple write.xlsx function in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and started with a quite simple task. I would like to gather tweets from different people and write them to an excel file, but I keep getting this error when trying to create a file:

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
```

This is my code so far:

```
tweets <- get_timelines(c("politician1", "politician2", "politician3", "politician4",  "politician5"), n = 200, max_id = NULL, include_rts = FALSE, lang = "FR", check = FALSE)
write.xlsx(x = tweets, file = "C:\\Users\\ME\\Documents\\Tweets.xlsx")
```

I tried lots of different things and am following an online tutorial and stuff, where these lines supposedly work. I am using the `rtweet` and `xlsx` package.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or tips.

Comment: I think you mean rtweet, not rtweets

Comment: Yes, of course. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the get_timelines function creates a data frame with 80+ columns, some of them seem to be in list format, which might cause the problem. For now, I reduce my dataframe by keeping the columns I actually need:

> df_tweets = tweets[c("user_id","created_at","screen_name","text", etc..)]

I have no issues since.

PS: With write.xlsx2() I was even able to save the whole table!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `library(openxlsx)` and then use

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(tweets, file = "tweets.xlsx", asTable = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me a new error: 

Error in x[is.na(x)] <- na.string : replacement has length zero